# UNIX permissions to allow group users to kill each others' processes

Tags: permissions, unix, process, kill

Let's say we have a group (`dev`) which has many users and a shared development directory with `g+rwx` permissions on all contained files.  Is this setup sufficient so that any `dev` user can kill a process launched by any other `dev` user (assuming the process was started with the default permissions)?

So for example, say we have file `/opt/devfolder/bin/foo` owned by user1 (in group `dev`) with group id `dev` and permissions 0770.  If user2 (in group `dev`) starts an instance of "foo" from his shell, can user3 (in group `dev`) kill it?

**[Edit]**

If not, how can we achieve this using `sudo` or some other standard UNIX utility?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to create an entry in `/etc/sudoers` like this:

```
%users localhost=(%users) NOPASSWD:/bin/kill
```

This will let anyone in the `users` group run `/bin/kill` as any other user in the `users` group, and will not prompt for a password.  I'm pretty sure this is exactly what you were asking for.

In this example I'm assuming that there exists a group named `users` to which all of the members of your dev group belong.  You will obviously need to modify this to match your local environment.

Answer (score 4):

Depending what your problem is, if you need the users of the **dev** group to be able to kill **all** of the processes of a specific type for some other user, then there might be a solution.

```
%users localhost=(%users) NOPASSWD:/bin/killall -u <username>
```

or

```
%users localhost=(%users) NOPASSWD:/bin/killall -u <username> perl
```

or whatever. you get the idea. This would allow the developers to kill all of the 'perl' processes, for one specific user. Remember that you can use the command aliases to shorthand writing out longs lists of apps, and you can also use regular expressions (be careful you don't allow too much)

Answer (score 2):

Group file permissions do not extend to running processes.  Only the owner of a process can kill the process.

However, you might consider configuring sudo to allow users the kill command in a limited manner.

Comment: +1 thanks for the clarification; I've updated my question to include advice on how to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Granting users to kill processes with `sudo` will allow them to kill any process. It cannot be restricted to only kill processes of a specific user.

Comment: So it sounds like the solution is to have a shared user account which will own all of the files and have the setuid bit on all executables, ya?

Comment: @maerics No. No. No. As mdpc correctly says (so I didn't duplicate this) file permissions are **not** related to process state permissions.

Comment: ok, thanks.  So any ideas on how to achieve this "process state group" permission I'm looking for?

Comment: @maerics Funny. If there would be a solution I had posted it. But there isn't.

Comment: @mailq, if the suid bit on the executables, then the process is owned by a specific user and this can be used to setup a kill command for that specific user in a sudo configuration.  Thus that approach would work!